# ViewPager how to only swipe view if overtop of PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Backstory:

I've been messing around with this for awhile now and can't find any decent documentation. I'm locked to having to support api level 8, and so view pager seemed like a good solution.  I've gotten it working with pagerTitleStrip.  However, I only want the user to be able to swipe between views when swiping on the pagerTitleStrip.  I have that working somewhat.

Issue:

When I swipe over top (touch_move) of a button, edittext field, etc.  The viewpager brings only a small chunk of the other view into the window.  I want nothing to happen unless the touchmove event to swipe between a view is ontop of the pagerTitleStrip.

Failed Attempt:

I've set the onTouchListener of the viewPager and any onTouch events actions(touchmove, touchup, touchdown)I use to determine if the user is swiping on the pagerTitleStrip.

```
//in onCreate()
...
setContentView(R.layout.pager_adapter);
dashboardPagerAdapter = new DashboardPagerAdapter(
getSupportFragmentManager());
dashboardViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_pager);
dashboardViewPager.setAdapter(dashboardPagerAdapter);
dashboardViewPager.setId(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
dashboardViewPager.setCurrentItem(DashboardPagerAdapter.DASHBOARD);
dashboardViewPager.setOnTouchListener(this);
...

// in onTouch
View pagerTitleArea = findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
    int pagerTitleBottomYLocation = pagerTitleArea.getBottom();
    initialYPositionOfEvent = 100; // set the initial position out of range.
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        initialYPositionOfEvent = event.getY();
        originWasTitleBar = (initialYPositionOfEvent > pagerTitleBottomYLocation) ? false : true ;
        hasTouchDownEventOccured = true;
        return true;
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if(originWasTitleBar && hasTouchDownEventOccured){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if(originWasTitleBar && hasTouchDownEventOccured){
            originWasTitleBar = false;
            hasTouchDownEventOccured = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            originWasTitleBar = false;
            hasTouchDownEventOccured = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "However, I only want the user to be able to swipe between views when swiping on the pagerTitleStrip" -- quoting the documentation for `PagerTitleStrip`: "PagerTitleStrip is a non-interactive indicator of the current, next, and previous pages of a ViewPager...  For an interactive indicator, see PagerTabStrip."

Comment: I did switch to PagerTabStrip, and that gave me the ability to click on the left and right side of the strip and switch to that screen which was also something I was trying to implement (thanks!).  I'm still unable to stop the viewpager from receiving the event to slide when the user touches an input box and swipes.

Comment: Why are you using a `ViewPager` if you do not want swiping? That's the **entire freakin' point of a `ViewPager`**.

Comment: I wanted swiping to only happen when the swipe was on the title/tab strip.  So that I could have left and right scrolling controls on the view for other things.  No need to get upset. If there is a better approach then I'm all ears.  If I knew exactly what to do I wouldn't be on stack overflow asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewFlipper with buttons for switching content, or use action bar tabs, or something like that, perhaps.